# For loops exercise in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

i am a beginner in MATLAB and i am asked to do an exercise to learn for loops. I have 5 numbers , 1 till 5 ( 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 ,5) and each of this number will exhibit a transformation process that consists of four stages such that for example  for 5  ( 5 will be --> 5( at the end of first stage) 4 ( at the end of second stage  3( third stage ) 2( second stage) 1 ( first stage)) , for 4 ( 4 ,4 ,3,2 ) , for 3 ( 3 , 3 ,3 ,2) , for 2 ( 2 ,2 ,2 ,1 ) and for 1 ( 1 1 1 1) . I need to output ( for each number ) the result at each iteration ( for example for 5 --> 5 ( iteration 1) , 4 (iteration 2 ) and so on ) , so can any one help me in this exercise ? Its confusing for me as a beginner . Thank you

Comment: Can you post something you tried so far, even if it does not work perfectly? We could provide you a solution, but you will learn much more if you try it first yourself. To find the error yourself, it may be helpful to run your code step by step using the [matlab debugger](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html).

Comment: It looks homework (I did not downvote, BTW). Here many won't recognize a homework as a legitimate question. I would suggest you to put some effort, bring it from a pure homework to some level of well-formed question, such that would engage developers to answer your particular question. In this way, you will learn much better and faster.

Comment: Thanks you guys for your reply . No its not an HW , i am just trying to do this idea for practice purpose only. Here is what i have reached :

Comment: for n= 1:5
    for q = 1:4
    end
end

Comment: The problem is that i cannot find the algorithm itself to use in the nested loop to produce the results .

Comment: guys , somebody help !

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [for loop](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) on mathworks.

It isn't particularly clear what you are asking, I suggest editing your question to make it clear what you want to do and what the problem you are having in doing that.

It seems like you should use just one for loop. You could subtract 1 from each element on each loop, but put a restriction in so the element won't go to zero. To help with that, you could use the [find function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the index of each element then inside the for loop you'd include a restriction if the element goes <1 set the element =1. That way you'll end up with all elements equal to 1 at the end of the iteration if run for 5 steps.

To output the iteration number each time, simply just put whichever variable you are iterating over inside the loop.

`for n=5:-1:1 %decrements from 5 to 1
     A-1;    %A is the vector you started with
     n    %by not suppressing the output with a semicolon will show the                          value of n in the command window. You could also use disp(n)
     indZeroEl = find(A==0);    %the index of any element equal to zero
     A(indZeroEL) = 1;
end`

I haven't got access to matlab right now to check this, but this should at least get you on the right lines.